# how to implement jquery noconflict in sails

Tags: jquery, sails.js

I am working on a sails project in which two different features are using two different versions of jQuery.

hence i have to load both jquery but in doing so last loaded file is overriding the previous loaded one.

I want to use **jQuery noConflict**, but dont know how it is done in sails as there is no order of loading file.

we can give the order in pipeline.js but still unable to get where to write noconflict command.

Comment: You're solving the wrong problem. The problem you should actually solve is the supposed need to load two different versions of jQuery. Don't do that. If you have plugins that require old versions of jQuery, upgrade, replace, or update them.

Comment: thankyou @T.J.Crowder I have tried but still not able to make it work for updated jquery. I will try to do that as 1 file that too updated one is always better then 2